# Jquery attr() is not working second time

Tags: jquery, attr

jQuery `attr()` is not working second time,
`editAsk` thing is working 
but `editDone` is not working. `editDone` attribute comes after the process of `.editAsk`.

```
    $('.editAsk').on('click', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('class', 'callEdit editDone');
    });
    $('.editDone').on('click', function(){
        var $this = $(this);    
        $this.attr('class', 'callEdit editAsk');
    });
```

Comment: events are bound to the element, not the selector. Changing the element so it matches another selector does not change what events are bound to the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use delegation this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.editAsk', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('class', 'callEdit editDone');
});
$(document).on('click', '.editDone', function(){
    var $this = $(this);    
    $this.attr('class', 'callEdit editAsk');
});
```

Doing it this way, would allow you to delegate the event handler to the existing elements, or any future elements that will be added/modified in the DOM.

You can read more on event [delegation using `on` here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: It would be useful in your answer to include _why_ he should use this method, so he can learn going forward.

Comment: It would have been worth at least highlighting or even copying the "For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents." part of the article linked. `$(document).on` binding should be a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.callEdit').on('click.doSmth', function(){
    var $that = $(this);
    if ($that.hasClass('editAsk')) {
        // do smth
    } else {
        // do smth else
    }
    $that.toggleClass('editAsk editDone');
});
```

One event, no need to use delegation. Just another way to do this.